# Does Xcode have code navigation feature?

Tags: xcode

Does Xcode have a code navigation feature? Like unix's cscope type of tool which I can enter the name of a class and it will open the file for me? Or find out the caller of a particular method of a class? Or show the type hierarchy of a class?

Answer (score 16):

<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> (Xcode 4: <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>) opens a Quick Open window where you can type a partial class name and hit enter to open the file. As far as more complex versions such as what Eclipse offers (method names, symbol names, etc), I don't believe anything like that is built into XCode.

Comment: You can type symbol names into the Quick Open window and they will generally be found.

Comment: XCode 4 has annoyingly changed Command-Shift-D to Command-Shift-O

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the Quick Open window, there is the class browser. The class browser allows you to view the class hierarchy. The Class Browser can be found under the Project menu.

Answer (score 3):

The "Jump To Definition" item is accessible through CMD + double click, which takes you directly to the relevant code

Also, you can "Jump To Documentation" by (Option or ALT) + double clicking on a class/method/property

Update:
Option + double click no longer takes you directly to documentation in Snow Leopard. Now it opens up a little documentation "bubble", with the option to jump to the documentation browser if needed.

Comment: Or Option, if you're not using a PC keyboard on your Mac.

Comment: Yeah, I don't even know why I wrote that. Still working those bad memories out in therapy…

Answer (score 2):

If you Ctrl click a class name, method name or function name you will get a long meny where you can find the **Jump to Definition** item.

Answer (score 2):

From XCode 4.4 upwards, you can find callers and callees by opening the "show related items" pop-up for a selected (highlighted) method:

1. Mark method in code (using your cursor or double click name)
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
3. Select "Callers" from the pop-up menu

You can also go View->Standard Editor->show related items or press the tiny button just left of the arrow buttons in the line just above the editor window (where it shows your currently selected file and method).

Answer (score 1):

Also: select an identifier, right-click on it, and choose Find in Project > As Symbol (or Find in Project and choose Symbol as the search type) shows all symbolic uses, that is, declarations, definitions, and call sites.

Answer (score 1):

There should opens up something like an element preview window or bubble when the user point to a method or item. The "Jump to Definition" change the users focus and take 2 steps to go to the target.

The relation window and context window in Source Insight is a good example,but I can't find them in Xcode and other dev tools for the mac.

By the way,the context window should have multiple layers to trace a deep referenced method like the split window in Xcode, not only one layer in the source insight.